# Is my way of reusing methods in JUnit tests bad?

Tags: java, mocking, reusability

Lets say I have a JUnit class called `Test.class`. `Test.class` has around 50 JUnit tests and on 30 JUnit tests, this line of code always appears:

Note: I'm using Mockito/PowerMock

`when(ConnectionHandler().getConnection()).thenReturn(connection);`

I'm planning to create a utility class called `TestUtils.class` and create a private method for the line above like:

```
public static stubConnection(Connection connection) {
    when(ConnectionHandler().getConnection()).thenReturn(connection);
}
```

So instead of writing down `when(ConnectionHandler().getConnection()).thenReturn(connection);` every time, I could just go for `TestUtils.stubConnection(connection)`;

Is this advised? I just see a lot of repetitive code in my JUnit tests. If it helps, I'm testing really a class that has very low cohesion and is very tightly coupled.

Comment: If it makes sense to you and saves you time, then yes it is a good idea.

Comment: I can see why you hesitate to do this. However, making a static method in a JUnit implementing class makes sense if you process isomorphic non-test-case related information multiple times in different tests. Just be careful and aware of what is lost in semantics to other readers when you create macro-like constants

Comment: @Savagewood After little refactoring, I just have a private method in `Test.class` named `stubConnection()` which basically does the same thing as `TestUtils#stubConnection`. However, I'm sure that method will also be used in other JUnit test cases - which is why I'm planning to move it elsewhere :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this advised? I just see a lot of repetitive code in my JUnit
>   tests.

Absolutely.  The fact that this is a unit test is (almost) not relevant, it's still code that you or someone else has to maintain. Encapsulating it into a util or service class is definitely a step in the right direction.

Comment: I'm concerned about readability though - is there any better way to make my unit tests readable assuming that I have to create utility classes for encapsulation?

Comment: I think the method you've created (`TestUtils.stubConnection(connection)`) is perfectly readable; it describes exactly what it does.  There is a certain complexity required when using mocking frameworks, hiding this complexity might make the code more readable but it will also make it a lot more mysterious!

Comment: Alright! For readability issues, I've decided to just import it statically so it would just appear as `stubConnection()` in my code. Thanks for your input!